# Even Fourier Series Function

Tags: fourier-analysis

QUESTION: I am trying to show that

$$a_n=-\frac {1}{\pi } \int_{-\pi }^\pi  f \left( t+ \frac {\pi 
}{n} \right) \cos(nt) \,{\rm d}t$$

will transform to this expression with a cosine shift, but I am uncertain how to do this here to obtain:

$$a_n=\frac 1 2  \frac {1}{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^\pi  \left[f(x)  -f \left( x+\frac {\pi }{n} \right) \right] \cos(nx)  \, {\rm d}x $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original definition of $a_n$ is

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\,{\rm d}x$$

and the equation you have derived reads

$$a_n = -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f\left(x+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\cos(nx)\,{\rm d}x$$

Adding these two equations gives us the desired result

$$2a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left[f(x) - f\left(x+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right]\cos(nx)\,{\rm d}x$$